# Como identificar um dispositivo USB?

Tags: c++, linux, usb

Tenho dois tipos de dispositivos (A e B) que comunicam de forma serial através da USB e podem ser conectados ao PC usando linux.

Existe uma forma de identificar qual dispositivo que está conectado sem ter que conversar com ele? Já que cada um seria tratado por um protocolo bem diferente?

Comment: Em linha de comando, no linux, tente o `lsusb`

Comment: Não testei, mas seguem 3 sugestões que talvez ajudem: [Linux USB](http://www.linux-usb.org/), para C/C++: [libusb](http://libusb.info/), e em  Java: [jUSB: Java USB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários... vou dar uma olhada. O lsusb me apontou para uma pasta do linux onde posso conseguir as informações e a libusb tem bastante potencial, vou checar também.

Comment: se estiveres à procura de penUsb ou discos tenta `lsblk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou responder aqui como acabei solucionando o problema antes de chegar a conversar com cada dispositivo.

**1)    libusb**

Esta biblioteca pode ser uma boa solução, mas acabei não testando porque eu não poderia manter a licença dela como ela se mantém atualmente. 
Achei também uma lib chamada RS232 que tem exemplos de vários tipos de métodos diferentes para Linux e Windows que recomendo para quem estiver aprendendo, ela funcionava até os dias de hoje (30/05/2016) mesmo no Windows 10 e no Linux.

Essa segunda tem uma licença mais tranquila, mas mesmo assim acabei não utilizando.

**2)    lsusb**

É possível com essa abordagem saber se houve uma mudança de estado nos dispositivos USB por esse caminho. 
Para conectar de fato depois, você deverá precisar de outra solução.

Comecei a fazer uma chamada de sistema para ver se havia mudado a quantidade de dispositivos USB e só então eu tentava conectar ou desconectar:

```
# lsusb | wc -l
```

O problema com essa abordagem é que a conexão e desconexão rápida de um dispositivo por outro ficavam sem detecção, já que eu olhava isso uma vez por segundo e era possível trocar um por outro nesse intervalo, mas é uma solução aceitável para testes.
Acabaria fazendo um diff do resultado atual do lsusb com o resultado do instante anterior, mas não cheguei lá por ter interrompido antes essa abordagem.

Também é importante notar que eu tentei encontrar algo que diferenciasse os dispositivos, mas o lsusb –v e tudo o que ele pode prover de informação não me foi útil.
E sim, essa é a solução mais útil disponível no Linux.

Como uso o mesmo tipo de cabo USB-Serial para os dois tipos de dispositivos que estou tentando conectar e todos respondiam a mesma coisa: Prolific PL2303, não consegui identificar o dispositivo sem tentar comunicar.
Se os dispositivos forem diferentes pelo comando lsusb, acredito que seja uma boa solução.

**3)    dmesg**

Analisei formas de olhar apenas para o dmesg e é possível e provavelmente melhor e mais garantido do que o lsusb de saber que houve uma mudança nos dispositivos USBs se você precisar do caminho dele depois (/dev/ttyUSB0, por exemplo).
Aqui é possível que ele mostre qual o dispositivo que foi conectado e se não mostrar, provavelmente é um problema de driver.

Entendo que é uma solução possível mesmo para muitos usar a combinação (lsusb e dmesg resolvem bem se for possível diferenciar os dispositivos pelo lsusb).
Mas no meu sistema essas mensagens estão desabilitadas para agilizar o tempo de boot no máximo possível, então não deu para usar essa solução também.

**4)    Lista de dispositivos**

Acabei contornando o lsusb/dmesg criando uma lista de caminho de dispositivos USB que podem ser conectados ao meu sistema:

```
char comports[MAXIMUM_COMPORTS][16] = {  "/dev/ttyUSB0", "/dev/ttyUSB1","/dev/ttyUSB2","/dev/ttyUSB3","/dev/ttyUSB4","/dev/ttyUSB5" };
```

O que eu faço é verificar se qualquer um desses está criado no sistema e se tiver, tento comunicar com ele usando os protocolos disponíveis de comunicação. 
Sua lista pode ser bem mais simples, talvez apenas o /dev/ttyUSB0 e /dev/ttyUSB1 resolvam para você.

Se o /dev/ttyUSB0 existir, tento abrir ele e comunicar como se fosse o dispositivo 1. 
Se falhar, fecho e tento abrir ele e vejo se comunica como se fosse o dispositivo 2.
Se falhar nos dois, eu tento novamente todos os dispositivos até 3 vezes na mesma porta e só então desisto.

Se comunicar, marco esse dispositivo como ativo e conectado até acontecer uma desconexão.

A forma de verificar cada dispositivo que usei foi o método stat do próprio c.

Answer (score 1):

Todo modelo de dispositivo tem um device ID único, que é uma combinação de um manufacturer ID (2 bytes) e model ID (mais 2 bytes). O manufacturer ID é atribuído pela entidade gestora do standard USB ao fabricante, e o model ID pelo próprio fabricante.

Como mencionou @Amadeus, você pode ver os dispositivos conectados e seus device IDs com o lsusb (parte do pacote usbutils). Com a opção -v ele apresenta dados detalhados do driver associado, p. ex. caminho(s) na pasta /dev, que deve ser suficiente para associar a identificação ao pipe que você vai abrir.

No seu programa, use a API da libusb para listar e identificar os devices.

[libusb: Device handling and enumeration](http://libusb.org/static/api-1.0/group__dev.html)